# Finding a chiddush of the Brisker Rov

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam, brisk

This question has a bit of an introduction to it.

Rav Shlomo Lorincz wrote a biography of the Chazon Ish, the Brisker Rov and Rav Shach, called במחיצתם (translated by Yonason Rosenblum as “In Their Shadow”; Feldheim, 2008). In the section on the Brisker Rov, he describes a time that Rav Shalom Schwadron visited the Rov with his son-in-law, Rav Eliyahu Dovid Reichman, to ask a shayla on the Rambam.

The Brisker Rov heard the shayla and told his own son, Rav Yoshe Ber, to answer it. Rav Yoshe Ber did so, and then proceeded to relate the circumstances under which his father arrived at this pshat.

They were fleeing Warsaw in 1939, and heading in the direction of Vilna. The Germans were bombing groups of refugees from the air, so the Rov and his family turned off the road. Under heavy aerial bombardment, they made their way to a copse of trees, where the Brisker Rov suddenly declared: “I have pshat on the Rambam!”

According to Lorincz, this story is told in Rav Shalom Schwadron’s biography, קול חוצב. I have been shown a copy of the relevant section online, but all that it adds to this story beyond what Lorincz relates is that the chiddush concerned Hilkhos Qorban Pesach. Does anybody know what Rav Schwadron’s shayla actually was? Does anybody know the pshat in the Rambam that Rav Yoshe Ber delivered in the name of his father?

Comment: Might help: Some classes on Pesachim by Rabbi Reichman: https://www.kolhalashon.com/New/Shiurim.aspx?Lang=Hebrew&RavID=-1&ROrder=-1&FID=88470&HideMenus=False Maybe he happened to mention the story somewhere in one of the classes. They're quite long, though, and in a Litvish style to boot...

Comment: In the book סיפורים קטנים על אנשים גדולים in Otzar Hachochmah it's said that it was about Hilchot Chametz U'Matzah.

Comment: Did you search in עובדות והנהגות compiled by Rabbi Meller? Maybe a quick look for the name "Schwadron"? I saw three pages in volume 4 that had Schwadron in it, but it is the paid-version, so I cannot check it.